# Is there a way to load streaming data from Kafka into HDFS using Spark and without Flume?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs, flume

I was looking if there is a way to load the streaming data from Kafka directly into HDFS using spark streaming and without using Flume.
I have tried it using Flume(Kafka source and HDFS sink) already.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Perfect candidatae: Spark Streaming

Answer (score 0):

There is [HDFS connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) for [Kafka Connect](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect). Confluent's documentation [have more information](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic function for Spark Streaming.  Depending on what version of spark and Kafka you are using, you can look at the spark streaming kafka integration documentation for the versions you are using.  Saving to HDFS is as easy as `rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs:///directory/filename")`.

[Spark/Kafka integration guide for latest versions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)